# MySQL to conserve line breaks

Tags: python, mysql

Hi I want to be able to store text in MySQL using Python that will conserve any line breaks. I was using `replace('\n', '<br>')` which worked fine until I realized that whenever the text had an apostrophe, MySQL errored so I did `con.escape_string(text)` but now this removed the effects of the replacement so I had a huge cluttered paragraph when it was posted.

Basically long story short, how can I implement a cgi.escape (to avoid HTML), a way to store apostrophes and other symbols in MySQL without an error, and a way to conserve line breaks. So a 
user can submit a text like this one and MySQl can store it, then it can be printed on a page as it originally looked when submitted.

Thank you!

Comment: It might help if you mentioned the data type of the field you are storing it in. There are definitely data types in MySQL (and any other RDBMS) that will handle newlines fine. Also, I would recommend against storing HTML in a database unless you are **certain** you will always only ever need HTML when you pull the data back out.

Comment: I'm using mediumtext. It stores the spaces in the database fine but when I get it back and print it, html ignores line breaks as they are just spaces and no <br> and created a mess.

Comment: Then you have misidentified your problem. MySQL _is_ preserving your line breaks, but HTML collapses them (as it should). Perhaps you mean, "how can I convert newlines to <br> when outputting HTML?"

Comment: Yes, you made me realized how flawed I am. I just needed to do the replacement with the string before I posted... not before I stored. I've been on the computer too long!

Comment: Sometimes an extra pair of eyes (and someone not so close to the problem) helps. We've all been there :)

Answer (score 3):

If the presence of return characters and apostrophe's is causing you problems, it is most likely that you are writing to the database in the wrong way. I suspect that what you are doing is something like:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES('%s')" % value)
```

where you are passing the data to be stored, as part of the SQL statement. This is generally the wrong way to do this, especially if you are using user provided data, as this exposes you to security issue, such as SQL injection attacks. You should *never* put user supplied data into the SQL statement, unless you have been extremely careful.

The correct way to do this is:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES(?)", (value,))
```

Where you use the question mark to indicate the data to insert, and pass the actual data in, as part of a tuple, as the second argument. This massively simplifies things, and means that you can store any data you want, without having to escape it, or worry about security issues.

Answer (score 0):

these two are totally different problem,

replacing `str.replace('\n', '<br>')` is totally a html based changes. you can do anytime either before storing in database either after selecting but before rendering html with that data.

where storing apostrophes (') is sql based problem. you need to replace all apostrophes(') by double apostrophes('') and all commas(,) by slash followed by comma(/,) for correctly storing data into database.

```
str.replace("'", "''") # replacing apostrophes by double apostrophes
str.replace(",", "\,") # replacing comma by slash-comma
```